# How to analyze a large wav file?

Tags: import, sound

I have a large wav file (100 Mb). Any operation on it is time consuming. For example, to Import it takes about 1-2 minutes.

The next step seems to be to figure out how it is encoded, since WAV files can be encoded in a lot of different ways. How can I determine the encoding? I tried using Take, but I found no meta information:

[image]

Note that every operation is taking a long time here, so I am hoping to figure out how to do this fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{encod,sound,data} = Import["ExampleData/rule30.wav",{{"AudioEncoding","Sound","Data"}}];

encod
(* "UnsignedInteger8" *)
```

Comment: I did see that possibility however it seemed very inefficient to me so I thought there would be an alternative. Are you saying I need to Import data 3 times or more to analyze it? Once to find the elements, once again to retrieve the element, then a third time to retrieve the data? The problem here is that some of the files I am processing could take 10 minutes or more to import. So doing this 4 or 5 times or whatever seems outrageous.

Comment: @TylerDurden See updated answer

Comment: Excellent, that makes a lot more sense now, thank you.